# Disabled workspace switcher on second monitor in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell

I've updated Ubuntu 18.04 from Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. On second monitor I see a workspace switcher on the right side, but it is always closed and does not react to any actions

[image]

In Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 it always opened and you can easily switch between workspaces and drop apps.

"Workspaces only on primary" is disabled.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by updating all Gnome Shell Extensions.

Answer (score 5):

install

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/

end enable "Show Thumbnails-Slider on additional monitors"